# Downloading zip folder onto server from download_script.php link

Tags: php, zip

Trying to download [this VIM plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981), specifically [this zip file](https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23483), which is a download_script.php link.

I tried

```
wget https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23483
```

but then, all I end up with is this file name (download_script.php?src_id=23483), and no zip file: download_script.php?src_id=23483

How do I get the .zip file to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
wget https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23483 -O emmet-vim.zip
```

The `-O` flag tells wget what to save the downloaded file as.

You could also try using `CURL` like this:

```
curl https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=23483 --output emmet-vim.zip
```